# What is the best practice for creating a dialog for each card-item without an activator using Vue, Vuex, and Vuetify

Tags: vuejs2, vuex, vuetify.js

I am attempting to use Vuetifies v-dialog without an activator, and use the state management from Vuex to programmatically open the dialog for each item in a list.  I am also trying to use single-file components. I have a v-for that generates the card components, that each has a child component that is the dialogue. The card component has a computed value of modalState from mapGetters. The card has an @click that invokes an action to mutate modalState, and the child component using v-model"modalState". I have done a few variations now, the latest creates as many dialogs as there are cards, and never changes modalState, I think I need a setter here and maybe a unique ID. I previously had it working very similarly with the problem of creating a stack overflow if I reopened the dialog and closed it again. watching it in Vue dev tools, I could not see why.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly Wellcome to stackoverflow. Please read the guidelines on posting an question. To better understand your problem we need to see your code examples.

In the meantime I created a gist which wraps the vuetify dialog into a component and can be called anywhere in your app being triggered by `v-model`. Just bare in mind that its done in typescript using vue-composition api.

https://gist.github.com/JeremyWalters/6673b072322fa19975ff8aa8b29e4e9c

```
<template>
  <v-dialog v-model="show" max-width="500px" transition="dialog-transition">
    <v-card>
      <!-- Dialog Title -->
      <v-card-title class="py-1 px-3">
        <span>{{title}}</span>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <!-- Close button -->
        <v-btn text icon color="primary" @click="show = false">
          <v-icon>mdi-close</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </v-card-title>
      <v-divider></v-divider>
      <v-card-text>
        <!-- Dialog Body -->
      </v-card-text>
      <!-- Dialog Action Buttons -->
      <v-card-actions>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <v-btn color="error darken-1" text @click="show = false">Cancel</v-btn>
        <v-btn color="green darken-1" text @click="action">Okay</v-btn>
      </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>
  </v-dialog>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import {
  defineComponent,
  watch,
  SetupContext,
  ref
} from "@vue/composition-api";
export default defineComponent({
  props: { value: Boolean, title: String },
  setup(props: any, context: SetupContext) {
    const show = ref(props.value);
    watch(show, (val: boolean) => {
      if (!val) {
        context.emit("input", val);
      }
    });
    function action() {
      // Do anything here if pressed okay
    }
    return {
      show,
      action
    };
  }
});
</script>
```